# When is mongoDB's count method optimized?

Tags: mongodb, count

I don't understand the optimizations described here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1752

To let you know what I'm trying to do, I have a website with a bunch of articles. I want to know how many views an article has gotten in the last 24 hours, week, month, or year. I was thinking of just having a views collection where each time an article is viewed, an entry is added to the collection. Each entry would have an articleID and timestamp. To see how many views an article has gotten over the last month, I would just count the number of view entries for that article that have a timestamp after one month ago.

If I had a compound index on [articleID, timestamp], could I do this count in O(1)?

Comment: Just ask, why don't you maintain a counter in cache? Even if you have an index on [articleID, timestamp], you counting will be in log(n), this is still B-Tree, you can use the mongo cloud monitor to see the B-Tree course number.

Comment: log(n), right. Thanks. I guess I was just attracted to the simplicity of this solution, although it may not be very practical. Maintaining a count would require either keeping a running total (adding a view, and then subtracting it a day/week/month later) or recomputing from scratch. The running total introduces some complexities with atomicity and stuff. One way or another, I'll probably end up having to use time bins rather than working with individual views. Then I could recompute based on a few time bins rather than all of the individual views. Unless I'm missing something.